# Can't figure out how to get from a JSON data object a specific value with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm beginner with JSON and AJAX. I have this PHP file with JSON data objects that i want to parse to get a specific value from the array.
For example i want to get the ID="almCrit" :

Here is my JSON Obj :

```
$currentArrayData['configAlm'] = array(
  array('blocName' => 'blockAlarmeContent',     'blocLVTwoName' => 'boxLV2Content', 'label' => 'Criticité',         'id' => 'almCrit'),
  array('blocName' => 'blockAlarmeContent', 'blocLVTwoName' => 'boxLV2Content', 'label' => 'Sans supervision',  'id' => 'almSansSup'),
  array('blocName' => 'blockAlarmeContent', 'blocLVTwoName' => 'boxLV2Content', 'label' => 'Non nominale',      'id' => 'almNonNom)
);
```

and here is what i tried to do :

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'Pages/index.php',
     type:  'get',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: 'action=loadBlocSite',
     success:function(data){                
        arrayOfData = data;         
        currentValue = arrayOfData;                        
        $.each(arrayOfData['configAlm'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
            console.log('alarme : '+ arrayOfData['configAlm']);  
        });                 
    }
});
```

`console.log('alarme : '+ arrayOfData['configAlm']);` outputs:-

> alarme : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

I want to get the ID of the first `[object Object]`

I tried this `console.log('alarme : '+ arrayOfData['configAlm'].id);` but it gives me

> undefined

Can someone please help me figure out how it works ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:-

```
$.each(arrayOfData['configAlm'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
   console.log('alarme : '+ arrayOfData['configAlm']);  
});
```

Need to be :-

```
$.each(arrayOfData['configAlm'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
   console.log('Id : '+ currentValue.id);  
});
```

You need to use `currentValue` there

If you want to apply ***some condition check*** then you can do something like below:-

```
$.each(arrayOfData['configAlm'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
   if(currentValue.id =="almCrit"){
     return false; // Will stop iteration immediately when id==almCrit
   } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i did while trying to find a solution, but for my case i did a for loop + the  same if condition, i'm going to try this one

Comment: thank you so much for your help and explanation, it helped me a lot to understand things.. the if condition works;  i put `$('#boxLV2Content').empty();` because here in my case  whenever i click in the id='almCrit' it dosn't clear the old one to show the new one...it keeps repeting it...the empty() doesn't do the work but it's not a big deal ,..thanks again :)

Comment: @Zinebs  glad to help you buddy :):)

Comment: @Zinebs  it's ok. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In fact what you are doing here is that you are printing the `array` in each iteration of the `.each`, and you were trying to access the `id` property of the `array`.

You need to log `currentValue` content instead of `arrayOfData`:

```
$.each(arrayOfData['configAlm'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
   console.log('blocName Id: '+ currentValue['blocName'].id);  
});
```

And to better see what's happening here you can just print the whole iterated element of the array like this:

```
$.each(arrayOfData['configAlm'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(currentValue));  
});
```